# How to calculate posts number?

Tags: count

I want to achieve something like this:

```
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    if ( $a = $b ) ) {
        // if true +1 to the result;
    } else {
        // if not true -2 to the result;
    }
}

echo 'Your result is X';
```

How to replace X with the result of a calculation?
How calculation code should look?

Comment: Ok, so where are you having trouble? There's no question here.

Comment: How to replace X with the result of a calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this

```
$result = 10;

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    if ( $a = $b ) ) {
        $result += 1;
    } else {
        $result -= 2;
    }
}

echo 'Your result is ' . $result;
```

This is the best I can do with the provided information

Comment: Thank you! That's what I'm looking for!